# Custom validation message for maxSize in FileInput

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

How to implement a custom validation message for maxSize in FileInput? Don't happen to see maxSize import from 'react-admin', only see maxLength, minLength and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const maxFileSize = (max) => {
  return (value) => {
    const sizeIsLarge = (val) => val?.rawFile?.size > max           
    return (Array.isArray(value) ? value.some(sizeIsLarge) : sizeIsLarge(value)) ? 'message.file.large' : undefined
  }
}

<FileInput 
  validate={maxFileSize(100 * 1024)}
  ... 
>
```

Documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Validation.html#per-input-validation-built-in-field-validators